# Filter form field values by language

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform, language

I have a specific requirement of showing categories of selected menu language only. So in my component, I have the field declared as below.

```
<field name="catid" type="categoryedit" label="JCATEGORY" description="JFIELD_CATEGORY_DESC" class="inputbox input-block-level" required="true"></field>
```

And in my Model, I am setting the field attribute dynamically based on the menu language.

```
public function getForm ($data = array(), $loadData = true)
{
  ....
  $language = JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();
  $form->setFieldAttribute('catid', 'language', $language);
  ....
}
```

It works perfectly fine. However the only problem is it shows only the list which are meant for the selected language only, for example en-GB will show only list of values which are assigned to the language en-GB.

I need to display all the field values which are assigned to the selected language as well as "All" (or "*", i.e. no language selected).

I cannot set two values to the same field attribute, setting it two time overwrite fist.

```
$form->setFieldAttribute('catid', 'language', '*');
```

This doesn't work at all

```
$form->setFieldAttribute('catid', 'language', $language.', *');
```

Anyone has any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Can you show the custom Form Field code i.e. categoryedit.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I couldn't find any possible solution to this. So I overridden categoryedit field type and changed the following code in getOptions method (the field can be created in your component's models/fields directory so that it can be referenced in your form xml)

```
// Filter language
if (!empty($this->element['language']))
{
    $subQuery->where('language = ' . $db->quote($this->element['language']));
}
```

to

```
// Filter language
$languages = array(JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag(), '*');
if (!empty($this->element['language']))
{
    $languages[] = $this->element['language'];
}

$subQuery->where('language IN (' . implode(',', $db->quote($languages)).')');
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for similar solution.

Comment: Hi there! Do you know why when I want to use the categoryedit field in my component with the option to allow Adding new categories, it requires to declare in the xml the allowAdd="true", while the Joomla core components do not have to declare this and work without even mentioning the allowAdd?

Comment: That's because the flag is set manually. Example - administrator/components/com_content/models/article.php, function `preprocessForm`, `$form->setFieldAttribute('catid', 'allowAdd', 'true');`

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your xml (models/forms/yourform.xml) field definition to include the extra option like this:

```
<field name="catid" type="contentlanguage" label="yourlabel"
description="yourdescription">
<option value="*">JALL</option></field>
```

JALL will be automatically translated to your language "All" word.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for answering, however you misunderstood the question. I do not want to show another category name, rather categories with language set to All. Hope you understand.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. First of all you are using a custom field (categoryedit) so you should check in the "categoryedit.php" to see how to handle this. By the way, have you tried to pass an array like this $form->setFieldAttribute('catid', 'language', array('en-GB','*')) ?

Comment: This is not a custom field, it is standard Joomla field. Yes, I tried the array and it gives error " Warning: It is not yet possible to assign complex types to attributes". And checked in categoryedit.php and has code **if (!empty($this->element['language']))
  {
   $subQuery->where('language = ' . $db->quote($this->element['language']));
  }** I believe this cannot be done as I see the above code is not designed to handle this. I am overriding the field now.